# In a Google Drive folder, have an external URL stored as a "file" that when clicked opens an external website

Tags: google-apps-script, url, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

**Problem:**  I am trying to figure out if there is a way to store urls in a Google Drive Folder alongside other files.  When you click on the url "file" to open the file from Google Drive, Google Drive would instead open the URL in a new tab

**Example:**  For example, I've created a Google Doc that has a URL within the Google Doc - see screenshots below.

[image: Google drive test folder]

[image: Google drive doc with url in it]

My desired behavior is to double click on the Google Doc, and instead of loading the Google doc load the URL within the Google Doc ([www.spotify.com](http://www.spotify.com)) in a separate window.

**Clarification:**  I don't need to use Google Docs, so if there is some other filetype, extension, or workaround that allows you to open a URL from a Google Drive Folder that would solve this as well.

**My steps that I've taken so far:**  So far I've taken a look in the Chrome Store and read through some of the Google Drive help documentation.  I did find [this article on handling an open URL in the Google Drive documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/integrate-open) but can't determine whether this is relevant.

Thanks in advance for any ideas you might have!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is a useful workaround for your situation, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hello @Adam! Sadly there is no method of achieving this directly as a user action or some sort script execution is needed. Have you tried the solution provided below? If yes, does it work for your use-case?

Comment: Yes, this will work as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

I think that in the current stage, your goal cannot be directly achieved. So it is required to use a workaround. For example, how about the following workaround?

In this workaround, as a sample, a dialog of Google Document is used. When a Google Document is opened, a dialog is opened. By this, the page is opened the URL by Javascript. When this is reflected in the sample script. it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Document. And, [please install OnOpen trigger to the function `myFunction`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). By this, when Google Document is opened, the dialog is automatically opened and Javascript is run, and then, the URL is opened.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var url = "###"; // Please set URL.

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<script>window.open('${url}', '_blank');google.script.host.close()</script>`)
  DocumentApp.getUi().showDialog(html);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this workaround, the URL can be opened. But, unfortunately, the opened Google Document cannot be automatically closed. I think that this might be a demerit.
- This workaround uses Google Document. I think that this can be also used for other Google Docs.

#### Reference:

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

Comment: This works as a workaround - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the extensive solution provided by Tanaike, I would also like to add the following:

You can file a request for a new feature for Drive such that Google becomes aware of the need for a functionality like this/similar to this. To do this, you will simply have to fill in the **Send feedback to Google** form:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do a workaround putting the link in Google slide > then download the slide as PDF > put the PDF in the Google Drive folder. With this, the team doesn't have to install Google Docs in their phone and you can put graphic on the PDF.